# Web Browser catching save file dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, file, webbrowser-control, savefiledialog

I am trying to automate a daily task that we do. We have to go to this website, login, press a button that will generate an excel file and open the save file dialog. Now I've been trying to automate this task by using a webbrowser object. I am able to successfully log in, navigate to a page and press the necessary button, but then the save file dialog opens and that is where I am stuck.

I would love to have this file saved to a specific location so that I can then open it up and do what needs to be done.

To recap, I have a web browser object that at some point in time a save file dialog opens up. I want to automatically have it save the file in a specific location on the server. All automatically with no manual intervention.